# Invalid versioned objects getting created

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle12c

I have a problem which I believe is an extension of ORA-04043 issue.
Whenever the database packages are deployed using 'CREATE OR REPLACE ..' option and then grants are given to the schemas to execute these packages, SYS_PLSQL_* TYPE objects are getting created in the grantee schemas which are INVALID.

The packages in question do contain pipelined functions and refcursor output functions.

I want to know -

- If this is a know issue
- Why are these objects getting created in the schemas which get the grants
- Why are the objects getting created in the grantee schema INVALID ?

I am using Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit.

Thanks.

Comment: If this is about [invoker/definer rights](http://www.dba-oracle.com/security/definer_invoker_rights.htm), then in 12.2.0.1 couple of fixes went in for many Oracle owned pl/sql procedures/functions.

Comment: I don't think this is about invoker/ definer rights.. might be related though.. thanks

Answer (score 0):

As discussed with a DBA here, this is some Oracle issue and will be fixed in 12cR2.

Here is a description for anyone who faces this issue - we have pipelined or cursor returning packages to expose data to end users. Oracle internally creates a 'TYPE' type object which has name 'SYS_PLSQL_*' for such functions in the schema where these functions are present.

When the consumer calls such a function from consumer schema, similar objects get created in their schema which reference the object in the original (our) schema. In case of any code change, this temporary object gets deleted in the original schema and a new object of similar nature gets created.

However in the consumer schema, a new temp object is created referencing the new temp object but the old object remains. Since its reference is deleted, this object becomes invalid. It may sometimes also cause deadlocks.

Solution: Get a DBA or someone who knows the schema password to drop these objects!